# Placing space after logo and realigning text

Tags: html

So I am trying to change the logo for a company I work for and when I tried to place it into the coding it screwed up the alignment of the header text. If someone could help me that would be great! I want the 5 groups of text to go right underneath the logo. With the logo aligning at the top left of the web page.[Example Image of what is happening now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCFPj.png)

Coding is:

```html
<div class="header">
    <img class="Logo" src="https://www.maxgalaxy.net/SiteData/730/MWI_Images/20161004203121998.png" style="display:block">
</div>
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/events-calendar/" target="new">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/#" target="new">SPONSORSHIPS/ADVERTISING</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/#" target="new">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/advertising/" target="new">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/history-1/" target="new">PARTY PACKAGES</a></li>
    <!-- 
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/contact-us/" target="new">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/employment/" target="new">Employment</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/#" target="new">Fundraising</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/the-blog/" target="new">The Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hsviceplex.org/gallery/" target="new">Gallery</a></li>
    -->
    <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where's your CSS?